# Will an .exe on a CD install on a computer without an operating system?

Tags: c++, operating-system, installation

I was thinking about creating a software which could be installed on a computer without an operating system (via CD); but I am not sure if it would install properly, as there is no OS for it to run on. (Using C++)

Comment: Such a software is either a bootloader or an OS. If your program is none of those, there's no sense in trying so hard to run it without an OS.

Comment: Your wording indicates you're missing more prequisite knowledge than one SO question can contain. I suggest you do some research on how operating systems and other programs that don't rely on an operating system work, and also what's inside a .exe file.

Comment: Depending on your application you could modify a livecd version of some linux distro that has wine and run your application directly from wine. Or possibly cut out some of the complication and make your application a linux based application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.exe files can only be run on Windows, DOS and a few other operating systems.
If there's no operating system installed, there is no way to run the .exe file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE

Answer (score 3):

.exe is an extension for Windows, so without Windows you can't execute the program (or wine on Linux, or DOS, etc). You need some kind of support (an OS) to run the program, if you're not planning to write an entire OS.

Answer (score 3):

no, thats not possible. To run .exe files/programs you need a OS.

cu
.tappa

Comment: What type of extension would I need then?

Comment: @Joe The extension is not the problem. You can not run a windows application without the windows API.

Comment: What extension would an installation for Windows use?

Comment: @Joe Mostly .exe but an exe is not an operating system. Its not bootable off of CD / iso ... You need an OS that implements the windows api to run an exe.